# Using glmnet engine in tidymodels to fit models with percent data as response

Tags: r, glmnet

I am interested in using penalized regression (LASSO) with the `glmnet` engine in `tidymodels` to fit a model with a response variable that is continuous and bound between 0 and 1. I am familiar with how to fit a model to this type of data using a more "standard" generalized linear modeling framework (say, using the beta family and a logit link with the `glmmTMB`package), but am a bit lost when using penalized regression (`glmnet`, `tidymodels`). To my knowledge, glmnet only accepts a few different families. Thanks for any thoughts or ideas!

I have tried a linear regression using the default gaussian family with glmnet/tidymodels, but I feel that I cannot rely on these results because the response data does not match this distribution.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine to specify `family = "binomial"`. This will enforce a sensible scaling of the residual variance (proportional to `p*(1-p)`). As long as there's nothing in the machinery of `glmnet` that specifically requires integer-valued responses, you should be OK (e.g., base-R `glm()` will warn you if you fit a model with a non-integer response, but will still give you sensible point estimates).

If you were doing this in `glm()` you would want to use `family = "quasibinomial"` to account for the fact that the data aren't actually binomial counts (and hence the conditional variance shouldn't be assumed to be *exactly* `p*(1-p)`), but as far as I know `glmnet()` doesn't actually make use of any assumptions about the scale of the dispersion (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158866/glmnet-with-quasibinomial-in-r) for an unanswered question with a useful comment).

@hannahfrick points out that `glmnet()`/`tidymodels` can handle `family=quasibinomial()`, but the reprex below shows that there's no point in this case ('special' families like `quasibinomial` are slower than the built-in ones like `binomial`).

```r
library(tidymodels)
data("two_class_dat")
system.time(
  p1 <- (logistic_reg(penalty = 0.1) 
    %>% set_engine("glmnet", family = quasibinomial(link = "logit")) 
    %>% fit(Class ~ ., data = two_class_dat) 
)
)
```

```r
system.time(
  p2 <- (logistic_reg(penalty = 0.1) 
    %>% set_engine("glmnet", family = "binomial") 
    %>% fit(Class ~ ., data = two_class_dat) 
)
)
```

`family = "binomial"` is about 10x faster than `family=quasibinomial(...)` (although in this case the difference is 0.012 vs 0.12 seconds!), and the results are equivalent:

```r
all.equal(augment(p1, two_class_dat), 
     augment(p2, two_class_dat), tolerance = 1e-5)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: glmnet [supports families used by `glm()`](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/reference/glmnet.html#details-on-family-option) since version 4.0 and we've enabled that in tidymodels in [parsnip v1.1.0](https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/news/index.html#parsnip-110):  
  
    library(tidymodels)
    data("two_class_dat")
    
    logistic_reg(penalty = 0.1) %>% 
      set_engine("glmnet", family = quasibinomial(link = "logit")) %>% 
      fit(Class ~ ., data = two_class_dat)